# Neo4j admin neo4j.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, neo4j, neo4j-spatial

I use "neo4j-admin" and "neo4j.rb" as the following links. https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j
https://github.com/andreasronge/neo4j-admin
After I install neo4j-admin gem, we cannot start the rails server and look like neo4j-admin gem doesn't work. We got this error.

```
LoadError: load error: jruby-openssl -- java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object)
```

This is our Gemfile and we use jruby-1.7.4

```
gem 'neo4j', '>= 2.2.3'
gem 'neo4j-community', '1.9'
gem 'neo4j-advanced', '1.9'
gem 'neo4j-enterprise', '1.9'
gem 'neo4jrb-paperclip', :require => 'neo4jrb_paperclip' 
gem 'aws-s3',:require => 'aws/s3' 
gem 'neo4j-admin'
```

I would really appreciated any help.

Comment: This seems not related to Neo4j, but rather to jruby-openssl? Maybe there is a JDK version clash? What Java version are you running?